# Unable to provide react component method as prop callback to another functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning reactjs and built a sample app similar to the [tic toe app from on reactjs official website](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

When I run the app below and click on one of the choice buttons, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAnswered' of undefined`. I can't see the difference between the way I have hooked on an instance method to onClick vs the way tic toe app did it. What am I missing?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Choice(props) {
    return (
        <li> 
            <button onClick={props.onClick}>
                {props.value}
            </button>
        </li>
    );
}

class ChoiceList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      choices: null,
      answered: false,
    };
  }

  setAnswered() {
    this.setState({
        choices: this.state.choices,
        answered: true});
  }

  renderChoice(choice) {
    return <Choice key={choice} value={choice} onClick={() => this.setAnswered()}/>;
  }

  showData(payload) {
    const answered = false;
    const choices = payload.choices;
    this.setState({choices: choices, answered: answered});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.showData({choices: ['Good', 'Bad']});
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.choices) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div id="choices">
      <ul id="unsortedList">
        {this.state.choices.map(this.renderChoice)}
      </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Question />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Append the following code to the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    choices: null,
    answered: false,
  };

  this.setAnswered = this.setAnswered.bind(this);
  this.renderChoice = this.renderChoice.bind(this);
  this.showData = this.showData.bind(this);
}
```

Check the link for your reference 
[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Out of the three, your answer worked fine but the idea of binding each method explicitly doesn't look neat to me. Is there are an alternate to make the binding happen implicitly? I would like to mention that unfolding `{this.state.choices.map(this.renderChoice)}`  into {this.renderChoice(0)}{this.renderChoice(1)} worked fine too but isn't neat enough because I would like to loop over the choices.

Comment: @comiventor  Yes, there is a solution which is a special ES6 syntax.  You could declare you methods by 

const setAnswered = () => {
    this.setState({
        choices: this.state.choices,
        answered: true});
  }

the same to  renderChoice  and  showData . 


But this special syntax is not standard yet, only works under special  babel preset configure. The good news is that the syntax is already supported if you are using creat-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "this" is bound to the onClick function in your Choice element and not to your component class. The following should work:

```
renderChoice(choice) {
  return <Choice key={choice} value={choice} onClick={this.setAnswered.bind(this)}/>;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is basically the same solution like the answr by @Zhli but without using a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your constructor should be, You have to bind the 'this' context to **setAnswered** .

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setAnswered = this.setAnswered.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      choices: null,
      answered: false,
    };
  }
```